# Prevent XDocument or XElement form Encoding content

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

When I call XDocument.Save it is encoding my html `<br/>` tag, is there a way to prevent this?

```
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(new XElement("desc","jon skeet <br/> knows, the <br/> answer"));
xDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/tempUploads/encodeTest.xml"));
```

OUTPUT IS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<desc>jon skeet &lt;br/&gt; knows, the &lt;br/&gt; answer</desc>
```

OUTPUT I WOULD LIKE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<desc>jon skeet <br/> knows, the <br/> answer</desc>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's expected behavior: You set the inner text of the `XElement` to that string. It needs to be encoded, otherwise it would create multiple tags.

As you actually want to have multiple tags, you need to create them. The easiest way would be to use `XElement.Parse`:

```
var content = XElement.Parse("<desc>jon skeet <br/> knows, the <br/> answer</desc>");
var xDoc = new XDocument(content);
```

Comment: A lot of fun when you move to HTML5 , `<br/>` then becomes just `<br>`

Comment: 1.) An XML document has nothing to do with HTML5. 2.) If he really is saving arbitrary user entered HTML, at that point the OP might realize that what he has now is actually what he *needs* and what he *wants* is not the correct way of doing it. My answer answered his question of what he *wants*.