# Parsing error while creating XML using XElement

Tags: xml

I am using this syntax:

```
new XElement("description", "<![CDATA[Localité: " + columns[1] + "<br>Code postal: " + columns[2] + "<br>Rue 1: " + columns[3] + "<br>Rue 2: " + columns[4] + "<br>Rue 3: " + columns[5] + "<br>Téléphone 1: " + columns[6] + "<br>Numéro de télécopie: " + columns[7] + "<br>Mail: " + columns[8] + "]]>")
```

Output:

```
<description>&lt;![CDATA[Localité: Localité&lt;br&gt;Code postal: Code postal&lt;br&gt;Rue 1: Rue 1 &lt;br&gt;Rue 2: Rue 2&lt;br&gt;Rue 3: Rue 3&lt;br&gt;Téléphone 1: Téléphone 1&lt;br&gt;Numéro de télécopie: Numéro de télécopie&lt;br&gt;Mail: Mail]]&gt;</description>
```

Expected Result:

```
<description><![CDATA[Localité: ABC<br>Code postal: 12345<br>Rue 1: strzzt 1<br>Rue 2: sterrt y<br>Rue 3: BP 226<br>Téléphone 1: 123456789<br>Numéro de télécopie: 123456789<br>Mail: abc@yahoooo.com]]></description>
```

HTML tags are encoded, is there any way to rectify this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838358/prevent-xdocument-or-xelement-form-encoding-content

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent XDocument or XElement form Encoding content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838358/prevent-xdocument-or-xelement-form-encoding-content)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `XElement.Parse()`:

```
parsedDescription = XElement.Parse("<![CDATA[Localité: " + columns[1] + "<br>Code 
postal: " + columns[2] + "<br>Rue 1: " + columns[3] + "<br>Rue 2: " + columns[4] + 
"<br>Rue 3: " + columns[5] + "<br>Téléphone 1: " + columns[6] + "<br>Numéro de 
télécopie: " + columns[7] + "<br>Mail: " + columns[8] + "]]>")

new XElement("description", parsedDescription)
```